# javascript - new Date('1611065280155').getDate() returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I am trying on the Google console.

new Date('1611065280155').getDate() which returns NaN and I was expecting 'yyyy/mm/dd' similar format.

How do I get the date from a milliseconds?

I was referring to https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/get+the+date+in+different+format+javascript but since there are many functions and got confused

Comment: DateTime does not exist in JavaScript. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) with a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters) as value for handing over epoch time.

```js
console.log(new Date(1611065280155));
```